# Material UI Box is not going down

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to place the Questions Box at bottom of screen but it is not working. This is what is currently being rendered. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UsFm.png)
Here is the attached code

```js
<Box width={matches ? "100%" : "35%"} flex={1} bgcolor={grey[200]} boxShadow="2px 0px 4px lightgrey" zIndex={1} display="flex" flexDirection="column">
    <QuestionTrackerBox
        {...restProps}
    />
    {!matches && 
        <Box style={{overflowY:"scroll"}}>
        <RecordedQuestionsList 
        {...restProps}
    /></Box>}
    {matches && <VideoInterviewBox
        getRef={(node) => getRef(node)}
        {...restProps}
    />}
    <Box alignItems="flex-end">
    <QuestionInformationBox
        onHandleNextButton={onHandleNextButton}
        onHandleStopRecording={onHandleStopRecording}
        {...restProps}
    />
    </Box>
</Box>
```

Comment: What's the chance you can create a working codesanbox? It will be easier to answer that way..

Comment: use <Box style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'coumn' }}>
<Box style={{flexGrow:1}}></Box>
{your code}
</Box>